# Dynamic resizing of image using PIL and tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I wanted to know if it was possible to resize the image dynamically(maintaining its aspect ratio). I made an image viewer app, but then the vertically long images overflow the screen, so i wanted to know a method to resize image, ive tried a way and its included below. But still im getting the same output that overflows the screen.

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from tkinter import *

screen_width, screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)

root = Tk() # this is your window
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(screen_width//2, screen_height//2)) # set size of you window here is example for 1/2 screen height and width

img = Image.open("picture_name.png")
width, height = screen_width//4, screen_height//4 

img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS) 

l = Label(root,image=img)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Still im getting an image that is not resized, dont know why.

Then i tried out this method, where I set a resolution, and it works fine for my screen. but if i were to send to someother people, it would not dynamically adjust.

```
desired_size = 950

im = Image.open('img.png')
old_size = im.size

ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])

im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
l = Label(root, image=img)
l.image = img
l.pack()
```

I would like to know a way to dynamically resize the image maintaining its aspect ratio as well, so no distortion takes place, like the Photos app in Windows 10.

Whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from glob import glob
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='white')
root.title('Image Viewer App')

def forward_image(event=None):
    global n
    n += 1
    if n > len(main_img)-2:
        forward['state'] = DISABLED
        root.unbind('<Key-Right>')

    else:
        backward['state'] = NORMAL
        root.bind('<Key-Left>', backward_image)

    im = Image.open(main_img[n])
    old_size = im.size

    ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
    new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])

    im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    l.image = img
    l.config(image=img)
    status.config(text=f'{n+1} of {total} images')

def backward_image(event=None):
    global n
    n -= 1
    if n <= 0:
        backward['state'] = DISABLED
        root.unbind('<Key-Left>')

    else:
        forward['state'] = NORMAL
        root.bind('<Key-Right>', forward_image)

    im = Image.open(main_img[n])
    old_size = im.size

    ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
    new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])

    im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    l.image = img
    l.config(image=img)
    status.config(text=f'{n+1} of {total} images')

def path():
    global main_img
    path = filedialog.askdirectory(
        initialdir='c:/', title='Select a folder with images')
    img_png = glob(path+'/*.png')
    img_jpg = glob(path+'/*.jpg')
    main_img = img_jpg + img_png


path()

n = 0
desired_size = 950

im = Image.open(main_img[n])
old_size = im.size

ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])

im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
l = Label(root, image=img)
l.image = img
l.pack()


forward = Button(root, text='Forward', command=forward_image)
forward.pack(side=RIGHT)

backward = Button(root, text='Backward', command=backward_image)
backward.pack(side=LEFT)
backward['state'] = DISABLED

total = len(main_img)
status = Label(root,text=f'{n+1} of {total} images',bg='white',font=('helvetica',10))
status.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.focus_force()

root.bind('<Key-Left>', backward_image)
root.bind('<Key-Right>', forward_image)
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: root.state('normal'))
root.bind('<F11>', lambda event: root.state('zoomed'))

if total <= 1:
    backward['state'] = DISABLED
    forward['state'] = DISABLED
    root.unbind('<Key-Right>')
    root.unbind('<Key-Left>')

if total == 0:
    messagebox.showerror('No image','Choose a directory with images.')
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: `desired_size` is width of one photo? I was just working something exactly the same, but with multiple images on one canvas instead of just one.

Comment: @HenryYik Yes for this example, ive just included one photo, i put it in a function and it gets applied to all photos, which comes one after the other on a key bind, like a gallery or image viewer app.

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ I saw that you wanted me to give an answer here, but Henry's answer is perfect. My answer would fundamentally be the same.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry the problem was that i cant get it to adjust dynamically, despite adjusting the size, either the image is too small or too big. Adjusting the size makes a significant change to it, i cant get it to be exact though

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ but "_when you understand my code you'll use it_" ... :D :D :D. I'm just messin' with you (hard). I'll take a look at this in a minute and spin a quick scale method.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Take your time, ill include the whole code so maybe you can get a better understanding.

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ no need to add any code. This is incredibly simple. You want to stick in a width and a height and have the largest dimension fill the corresponding requested dimension.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Ive already edited tho, because sometimes, some methods might not work with what ive implemented, anyway its fine, ill follow your method.

Comment: Have you tried out thumbnail from PIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya' go. With a `scale` of `1.0` or lower the image will **always** fit in it's master. This answer is based on @HenryYik answer, but made more dynamic through the addition of the `scale` argument, and the logic to consider overflow in every direction. Also, instead of being based on window screenspace it's based on master screenspace, and that consideration is made in `resizing`, as opposed to in `__init__`.

other changes:

- Using `super()` to `__init__` a superclass is not ideal, so that part has been changed to a more strict syntax.
- Unless you have a running list in your head of the exact order of all `kwargs`, for every widget, you will never use `*args`, so it has been omitted.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#configure root
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Image Viewer App')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.config(bg='#222222',bd=0,padx=0,pady=0,highlightthickness=0)
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: root.state('normal'))
root.bind('<F11>', lambda event: root.state('zoomed'))
    

class Slide(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, image_path:str='', scale:float=1.0, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.configure(bg=master['bg'])
        self.img   = None if not image_path else Image.open(image_path)
        self.p_img = None
        self.scale = scale
                
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resizing)
        
    def set_image(self, image_path:str):
        self.img   = Image.open(image_path)
        self.resizing()

    def resizing(self, event=None):
        if self.img:
            iw, ih  = self.img.width, self.img.height
            mw, mh  = self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()
            
            if iw>ih:
                ih = ih*(mw/iw)
                r = mh/ih if (ih/mh) > 1 else 1
                iw, ih = mw*r, ih*r
            else:
                iw = iw*(mh/ih)
                r = mw/iw if (iw/mw) > 1 else 1
                iw, ih = iw*r, mh*r
                
            self.p_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.resize((int(iw*self.scale), int(ih*self.scale))))
            self.config(image=self.p_img)



total     = 0
slide_num = 0

def get_slides():
    global total
    path  = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='c:/', title='Select a folder with images')
    cache = glob(path+'/*.png') + glob(path+'/*.jpg')
    
    total = len(cache)
    if not total:
        m = messagebox.askyesno('No Images','The directory you have chosen does not contain any images. Try Again?')
        if m:
            return get_slides()
        else:
            root.quit()
            exit(0)
        
    return cache


image_cache = get_slides()


def commit_slide(n, t):
    slide.set_image(image_cache[n])
    status.config(text=f'{n+1} of {t} images')

    
def next_slide(event=None):
    global slide_num, total
    slide_num = (slide_num+1)%len(image_cache)       #wrap
    commit_slide(slide_num, total)
    
root.bind('<Key-Right>', next_slide)


def previous_slide(event=None):
    global slide_num, total
    slide_num = range(len(image_cache))[slide_num-1] #wrap
    commit_slide(slide_num, total)
    
root.bind('<Key-Left>', previous_slide)


#init display widgets
slide = Slide(root)
slide.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='prev', command=previous_slide).place(relx=.02, rely=.99, anchor='sw')
tk.Button(root, text='next', command=next_slide).place(relx=.98, rely=.99, anchor='se')

status = tk.Label(root, bg='white', font=('helvetica',10))
status.place(relx=.5, rely=.99, anchor='s')

#init first slide
commit_slide(slide_num, total)

root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yess it seems to workk, but you see in my functions, i used config method to update the labels with images, how do i do it here, such that the image, gets updated with the label as well?.and weird enough, i removed the `root.geometry()` and i noticed the app is increasing its size on its own, like an animation? why is that?

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ simple, add a little interface to `DynamicImage` that allows you to easily assign a new image, and rewrite your entire script. I already did it for you (see my answer). I changed everything. Your code was trying too hard to be suppressive, instead of barely trying and being more "allowive".

Comment: Thanks alot that has fixed alot of problems, uk anyways to make the label background transparent? and also if i actually close the `filedialog` without choosing, anything it choose a directory always, anyway to overcome that?

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ every problem has been solved. You can't make the background transparent, but you can make it the same color as the master. Filedialog is fixed, too. You'd be a lot better at programming if you actually figured this stuff out yourself. Just saying ... and dead serious. There isn't a single concept in this script that could be considered 'advanced'.

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ It doesn't have to be sad. Study my script. Learn what I did and why I did it. I'll give you a tip. Learning how to program is dead-simple, all the info you could ever need has already been written, in whole or part, somewhere. Learning how to think like a good programmer AND have a debugger going on in your head is the hard part. `print` is the best friend you ever had in your life. It allows you to investigate, which allows you to find clues, and formulate ideas that lead to solutions. Creating solutions is your entire job.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but below I defined a `class` that always resize its image `width` to 950, and height to original `height*delta`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

class DynamicImage(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master=None, image_path="", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.width = master.winfo_screenwidth()//2
        self.height = master.winfo_screenheight()//2
        self.img = Image.open(image_path)
        self.p_img = None
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resizing)

    def resizing(self, event=None):
        w, h = self.img.width, self.img.height
        if w>h:
            delta = self.width/w
            new_width, new_height = self.width, int(h*delta)
        else:
            delta = self.height/h
            new_width, new_height = int(w*delta), self.height
        self.p_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.resize((new_width, new_height)))
        self.config(image=self.p_img)
        s.config(text=f"Dimension: {self.p_img.width()}x{self.p_img.height()}")

s = tk.Label(text="")
s.pack()

DynamicImage(root, image_path="your_path").pack(fill="both",expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

If you modifty it a bit and pass the width/height according to actual window value, it can shrink or grow as well.

Comment: But what if i want to do dynamically? depending on the users screen size?because 950 works for my screen, not sure if it works fr something with lower resolution?

Comment: Sure but what do i replace? 950 is not my resolution either, it just happen to shrink the image such that it fits the screen.

Comment: It works fine with 1 pic but when i load a bigger sized image, it still overflows the screen.

Comment: That weird, mine is jus 1080x1920

Comment: is 1920 the height? If you want to take care of vertical images, you need additional checks to decide whether width>height or height>width, and then adjust the delta.

Comment: Yes its a vertical image. Oh could you tell how to do that too?

Comment: Yessss the image has been lowered made small, but the image is too small, any way to increase image size a bit?

Comment: Just change the num in `self.height = master.winfo_screenheight()//num` to a ratio you like.

Comment: the min value num can go is 1 right? 1 seems too big :( and 2 seems too small

Comment: Obviously you can do `master.winfo_screenheight()*3//4`...