# How to slide images one by one constantly using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I am learning Tkinter in Python. I am trying to make a slide changer of images one by one constantly without button. The images will be automatically changing after some delay. I am using for loop to iterate my image files from my directory but when i am giving just one image in the directory then the image is bliting on the tkinter pop-up display but when i am giving more than one images that time my images aren't showing up on the display.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import time
path = "Album"
root = Tk()
root.geometry("576x432")

location  = os.listdir("Album")
print(location)
#Output: ['1 (1).jpg', '1 (2).jpg', '1 (3).jpg', '1 (4).jpg', '1 (5).jpg', 'not out.png', 'out.png', 'pending.png']



for iteam in location:
    image1 = Image.open(f"Album/{iteam}")
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    photo_label1 = Label(image=photo1)
    photo_label1.pack()
    time.sleep(2)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `time.sleep(2)` this will freeze your GUI, i think indexing over the list and repeating the function using `after()` is much better

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said earlier, Ive gathered the code here to show the image on repeat after ever 2 seconds(2000 ms). Ive commented the below code to maximum to make it easier to understand on the go.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from glob import glob
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.geometry("576x432")

path = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Choose the directory with images') #get the directory path
location1  = glob(f'{path}//*.png') #get the path of all png image
location2 = glob(f'{path}//*.jpg') #get the path of all jpg image
final_loc = location1 + location2 #combine those list to a final main list
print(final_loc) #check the list
#Output: ['1 (1).jpg', '1 (2).jpg', '1 (3).jpg', '1 (4).jpg', '1 (5).jpg', 'not out.png', 'out.png', 'pending.png']

i = 0 #set the index value to 0
def show():
    global i #so that the value of i changes on global scope
    try: 
        image1 = Image.open(final_loc[i]) #open the index-th image
        photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        photo_label1.config(image=photo1) #using config so the image doesnt overlap
        photo_label1.img = photo1 #keeping a reference
        i += 1 #increasing the index number
    except IndexError: #if no more items in the list to index
        i = 0 #set index back to 0
    finally:
        root.after(2000,show) #keep repeating the function every 2 sec or 2000 ms

photo_label1 = Label(root) #create a label, later to be editeed
photo_label1.pack()

show() #call the function

root.mainloop()
```

I've made the example as much as dynamic as possible. You get to choose the directory and I changed `os` with `glob`, which is good for this case, I believe. You can go further and add another button to stop the "slideshow".

Its not good to use `sleep()` with tkinter as it will freeze your GUI while its waiting. So instead use the tkinter method `after(ms,func)`.

**`after()` method takes two arguments mainly:**

- `ms` - time after which the function should be ran in millisecond(ms)
- `func` - the function to run after the given ms is finished.

Though bigger images might not fit into your screen, that is a whole new Q, anyway I've already asked a similar Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787755/dynamic-resizing-of-image-using-pil-and-tkinter).

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @BappyAhmed Would appreciate marking as the answer.