# A countdown timer that runs in the background and interacts with other functions

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, timer, countdown

I've been looking around for this but all the solutions feel extremely complex and even then I haven't been able to get it to work how I want it. I'm making a program that randomly opens an image from a folder, waits 10 seconds, then opens another random image from the same folder, and keeps going.

Simple enough, I was able to do it in a While True loop and making the "wait 10 seconds" part with time.sleep(10). But, I'd like to have a button that simply resets it whenever I feel like it. I'm doing this in `tkinter` and I have a button that starts it, but when I added a button to reset it, I haven't been able to click it and when I try to, the program crashes. That's because it's in the time.sleep(10) and the whole program stops for 10 seconds. For anyone curious about the code, here it is.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import os
from PIL import Image
import time

root = Tk()

def AnmuViewer():
    while True:
        random_pic = (random.choice(os.listdir("D:/de_clutter/memez/anmu")))
        openPic = Image.open('D:/de_clutter/memez/anmu/' + random_pic)
        openPic.show()

        time.sleep(10)

        continue

def Restart():
    AnmuViewer()

start_btn = Button(root, text = "Start", command = AnmuViewer)
start_btn.pack()

next_btn = Button(root, text = 'Restart', command = Restart)
next_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I know I don't *need* a "Restart" button as being able to click the "Start" button again would've done the same thing. Either way, that "Start" button itself is also unclickable.

I've looked into threading so I'm thinking of making a function that counts down from 10, and when it reaches 10, the `AnmuViewer()` starts over again, that way I can click "Start" again whenever and reset the whole code from scratch. But I just haven't been able to get that to work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do not use `time.sleep` with Tk. You have to keep processing events. Instead Tk provides an `after` method to allow you to schedule a function to be run using the event loop.  eg: root.after(1000, lambda: print("hello")) to print hello after 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `start` and `reset` in the same button, but you can also add a reset button that calls the same function (commented code).
That is upon start, the system is reset to its initial state, here with the `callback` value set to `None`.

Most times, it is better to use `tkinter.mainloop` than a custom `while` loop. Using `time.sleep` in GUIs is usually a recipe for disaster as it blocks all interactivity during its execution.

I replaced the images with a `text label` for simplicity, you will have to change that.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def anmu_viewer():
    global cb
    random_pic = random.choice(images)
    lbl.config(text=random_pic)
    cb = root.after(10000, anmu_viewer)   # keep a reference of the callback

def reset():
    global cb
    if cb is not None:
        root.after_cancel(cb)             # cancel the callback
        cb = None                         # reset the reference to the callback to None
    anmu_viewer()


images = ['im1', 'im2', 'im3', 'im4', 'im5', 'im6']

root = tk.Tk()
cb = None    
lbl = tk.Label(root, text='')
lbl.pack()
start_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=reset)
start_btn.pack()
# reset_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=reset)
# reset_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `while` with tkinter will cause some issues with `mainloop()` and will freeze the issue. You should be using `after(ms,func)` which does not freeze the GUI. A very simple code can do this, take a look here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from glob import glob #for the path of the image
import random

root = Tk()

def anmuViewer():
    global cb
    choice = random.choice(all_img) #random choice of image from the list of img
    cur = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=choice) #make an image object
    img_label.config(image=cur) #changing the image on the label
    img_label.img = cur #keeping a reference to the image

    cb = root.after(10000,anmuViewer) #repeating the function every 10 second

def restart(): #reset func from Roblochons code
    global cb
    if cb is not None:
        root.after_cancel(cb)
        cb = None
    anmuViewer()

path = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Choose the directory with images') #ask the directory with the image.

png = glob(path+'/*.png') #pick all the png image
jpg = glob(path+'/*.jpg') #pick all the jpg image
all_img = png + jpg #concatenate both the list

img_label = Label(root) #image label, later to be configured
img_label.pack()

start_btn = Button(root, text = "Start", command=anmuViewer)
start_btn.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

next_btn = Button(root, text = 'Restart', command=restart)
next_btn.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I've explained the code with comments so its easier to understand on the go. I've not assumed what path of image you have, so I'm choosing the paths dynamically as you can see. The code looks long, because I simplified most lines of code to understand better.

Anyway you will need to resize the image so that it fits the screen for everyone, because pixels and screen resolution varies from device. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787755/dynamic-resizing-of-image-using-pil-and-tkinter)