# How to make a image viewer with left right functionality in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, image-viewer

I have bunch of links and labels in `list` to view those I want to make a image viewer with *next*, *previous* functionality. My links and labels for respective images are in `list`. Up to now I had tried this :

```
urls=[url,url1,url2,url3]
labels=["label 1","label 2","label 3","label 4"]

images=[]
for ur in urls:
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(ur).read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    images.append(image)
```

Now I have images ready in `images` and now I want to display it in image viewer but only last image is visible in image viewer.

```
Label(root).grid(row=1,column=1)

for i in range(len(images)):
    image_label=Label(root,image=images[i])
    image_label.grid(row=1,column=2)
    
    name=Label(root,text=labels[i])
    name.grid(row=2,column=2)

def left():
    image_label=Label(root,image=images[i-1])
    image_label.grid(row=1,column=2)

def right():
    image_label=Label(root,image=images[i+1])
    image_label.grid(row=1,column=2)
    
left_button=Button(root,text="Left",command=left)
left_button.grid(row=2,column=1)

right_button=Button(root,text="Right",command=right)
right_button.grid(row=2,column=3)
```

Right button is not working and left button is working but for one time only. When I click left button second time then nothing is working.
Error while clicking in right button :

```
line 45, in right
    image_label=Label(root,image=images[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63787755/13382000) code might help you

Comment: @CoolCloud actually yeah, and if I had found that I sure will not ask/answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Should just update a image label when shift left or right, not create a new label.
Using modulus `%` to find which one next turn.

To reduce code and executable, I use the image data in PySimpleGUI and simple name for image here.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def shift(num):
    global index
    index = (index + num) % size
    label1.configure(image=images[index])
    label2.configure(text =labels[index])

root = tk.Tk()

images = [tk.PhotoImage(data=image) for image in sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST]
size = len(images)
labels = [f'Image {i:0>2d}' for i in range(size)]
index = 0

label1 = tk.Label(root, image=images[index])
label1.grid(row=1, column=2)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text=labels[index])
label2.grid(row=2, column=2)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="<LEFT",  width=6, anchor='center', command=lambda num=-1:shift(num))
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="RIGHT>", width=6, anchor='center', command=lambda num=+1:shift(num))
button2.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: **But** What about `Label` in question there is asked about `Label` as well. :D I believe you can add that `Label` part too.

Comment: If you mean the name label, also create only a name_label, and update option `text` of name_label with labels[index] at the same time in callback function `shift`.

Comment: I don't want answer, I already added my answer and I know how to add label but I am asking you to add label part too in your answer because in question I had actually asked for label and links.

Comment: Jason: FYI, the `grid()` method always returns `None`, so that's the value being assigned to both `button1` and `button2`. See [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name).

Comment: Update as above.

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty close to original posted example.

There is no `lambda` in `Button`, just straight forward `command` that gives access to left and right functions.

The name label is unnecessary as `label` objects already have a `text` attribute so I've integrated image and text into single `label` and increased the font size.

`label` compound is used to control where the image is display relative to the text, I've chosen `top`. That is, the image will be place above the text.

The use of `global` in functions keeps track of `count`

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import io
import requests
import urllib 

root = Tk()
urls = [url, url1, url2, url3]
labels = ["label 1","label 2","label 3","label 4"]
count = -1
images = []
for ur in urls:
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen( ur ).read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO( raw_data ))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    images.append(image)

def left( ):
    global count
    count = (count - 1) % len(images)
    image_label.config(image = images[count], text = labels[count])

def right( ):
    global count
    count = (count + 1) % len(images)
    image_label.config(image = images[count], text = labels[count])

image_label = Label(
    root, image = images[count], font = "Helvetica 20 normal",
    text = labels[count], compound = "top")
image_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

Button(
    root, text = "<< LEFT", command = left).grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
Button(
    root, text = "RIGHT >>", command = right).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "ew")

right( ) # display first image
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually better explanation then other answers. And yeah! Close to original code. :)

Comment: Good one @Xitiz. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it by showing and hiding pairs of `Label`s with the image and it name on them. For development and testing purposes, it loads the images from disk instead of downloading them, but you can easily replace that with what you have in your question.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Button, Tk, Label


root = Tk()
root.title('Image Viewer')

# Create thumbnails of all the images.
image_folder = '/path/to/image/folder'
images = []
for filepath in Path(image_folder).iterdir():
    img = Image.open(filepath)
    w, h = img.size
    if w > h:
        f = 100 / w
        nw, nh = 100, int(f*h)
    else:
        f = 100 / h
        nw, nh = int(f*w), 100
    # Offsets to center thumbnail within (100, 100).
    woff, hoff = (100-nw) // 2, (100-nh) // 2
    img = img.resize((nw, nh), Image.BICUBIC)  # Shrink so largest dimen is 100.
    thumbnail = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255, 0))  # Blank.
    thumbnail.paste(img, (woff, hoff))  # Offset keep it centered.
    images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(thumbnail))

names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']

def get_images():
    """Create all image and name Label pairs but initially  hidden."""
    global image_labels, name_labels

    image_labels, name_labels  = [], []
    for i, (img, name) in enumerate(zip(images, names)):
        image_label = Label(root, image=img)
        image_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
        image_labels.append(image_label)

        name_label = Label(root, text=name)
        name_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
        name_labels.append(name_label)

        hide(i)

def hide(i):
    """Hide specified image and name pair."""
    image_labels[i].grid_remove()
    name_labels[i].grid_remove()

def show(i):
    """Unhide specified image and name pair."""
    image_labels[i].grid()
    name_labels[i].grid()

def shift(direction):
    """Display the image and pair before or after the current one that is
    `direction` steps away (usually +/-1).
    """
    global current
    hide(current)
    current = (current + direction) % len(images)
    show(current)


left_button = Button(root, text="Left", command=lambda: shift(-1))
left_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

right_button = Button(root, text="Right", command=lambda: shift(+1))
right_button.grid(row=2, column=3)

get_images()
current = 0  # Currently displayed image.
show(current)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of it running:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Actually unique approach. :) but is this really a better approach then other?

Comment: Whether it's better depends on what qualities you consider important of course. The good things about it are it's largely data-driven and once everything's set up, showing different image and associated name label-pairs is simply a matter of hiding and unhiding a couple of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label,Button
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import io
import requests
import urllib 

root=Tk()

count=0 # To know the current image and label
urls=[url,url1,url2,url3]
labels=["label 1","label 2","label 3","label 4"]

images=[]
for ur in urls:
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(ur).read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    images.append(image)

def change(direction): # Function to change image
    global count
    if direction=="left":
        if count<=0:
            count=len(urls)-1
        else:
            count-=1
    else:
        if count>=len(urls)-1:
            count=0
        else:
            count+=1
    name.config(text=labels[count])
    image_label.config(image=images[count])

Label(root).grid(row=1,column=1)
image_label=Label(root,image=images[count])
image_label.grid(row=1,column=2)

left_button=Button(root,text="Left",command=lambda : change("left"))
left_button.grid(row=2,column=1)

name=Label(root,text=labels[count])
name.grid(row=2,column=2)

right_button=Button(root,text="Right",command=lambda : change("right"))
right_button.grid(row=2,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Art If I want then I can don't provide any code but I had provided code just to show a simple example like... Should I delete code from question?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your last comment. You should at least explain what you changed *you can try this* doesn't explain anything.

Comment: I mean Do I have to remove the code from question? If I want then I don't have to provide any code in question, I can just right answer and that is okay! I hadn't explained it because one thing code is self explanatory and second code in question I had already explain what I am trying to do!

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. Showing an IndexError is what's making this post ambiguous. Besides, all codes are self-explanatory once you know what it is. Beginners might find it hard to understand.

Comment: Have you read _Right button is not working and left button is working but for one time only. When I click left button second time then nothing is working.
Error while clicking in right button :_ explanation? And if beginners wants explanation then they have to look at the question also, now looking at answer only help them to solve their problem. And in question I am clearly telling what i am trying to do! I gave that error message in question just to show this is also an issue for me.

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: @CoolCloud Exactly, I had actually posted answer, but we need question so question with answer. :)